# Encrypting an extra partition with ecryptfs?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I have an extra ext4 formatted partition which I would like to ecrypt with ecryptfs. I have chosen not to go for home directory ecryption and having a encrypted private directory also hasn't helped me.

So, the remaining option for me is to encrypt the extra partition. So, I want to know what is the best way to achieve this. The drive should get mounted when I log in. And I should be able to move my Documents and other important folders in the home directory to the encrypted drive, and symlink them back to the home directory. As I save some passwords in firefox, should I move the hidden firefox folder in the home directory to the encrypted drive?

Comment: May I ask why do you want to do this, since you are trying to create exactly the same thing as encrypted home? Is it space? I would just move home to the other partition.

Comment: I share my pc with my pals. And it is not possible to turn off automounting of home directory if I wanted it. If I have a ~/Private encrypted directory, I can turn off auto mounting If I wanted, but, the directory is visible so it can be easily deleted. If it is a drive it is more safer, and, as it is noticable during OS re-installs,so it's, according to me, a safer option. If I disable automounting, it is easy to convince my pals that it is a hidden OS backup drive.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to use an "Encrypted Private" directory. This will make `~/Private` encrypted, and you can move trees into there and symlink to them (for firefox, etc). It is very easy to set up:

```
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
ecryptfs-setup-private
```

Now just log out of your session and back in, and you'll have an encrypted `~/Private` directory automounted. You can move things into it like this:

```
cd ~
mv .mozilla Private/
ln -s Private/.mozilla .
```

For more details, see "man ecryptfs-setup-private", or [read the manpage online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/encryptfs-setup-private)

Answer (score 0):

You should know that if a person has physical access to the machine, there is little thing you can do to prevent deletion or other evil actions, be it a directory or a partition: they can still boot with a CD if you put "passwords-everywhere".

For directories, you can also use encFS which is very nice.

For partition, if you want deniability (eg. possibility to deny it is no more than a spare partition), the only option you have is TrueCrypt. But if you automount it you'll loose deniability as a script can be found that mounts this partition.

So, to really "hide", you have to mount manually.

Comment: plain dm-crypt has no header, and should in theroy be as deniable as TrueCrypt... maybe more so since I read about a TrueCrypt-finder once.  And no encrypted data is really *hidden* since it's giant blocks of pseudo-random data, anyone who sees it knows *something* is going on. Also read that the "hidden container" feature in TrueCrypt really only puts you in danger of everyone automatically assuming that you do have a hidden container, so you'll be questioned/prosecuted/tortured even more if you actually don't have a hidden container.